# Problem with Documentbuilder.parse()

Tags: java, document, lotus-notes, xml-parsing

im trying to parse some XML from a given URL. The code is as follows:

```
try {

                URL myUrl = new URL(sURL);
                URLConnection c = myUrl.openConnection();

                c.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                c.setReadTimeout(5000);

                org.w3c.dom.Document doc = readXml(c.getInputStream());}
```

/////

```
public static org.w3c.dom.Document readXml(InputStream is) throws SAXException, IOException,
            ParserConfigurationException {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setValidating(false);
            dbf.setIgnoringComments(false);
            dbf.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder db = null;
            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            org.w3c.dom.Document doc = db.parse(is);    
         return doc;
        }
```

Im given the exception:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: subUrL.mydomain.com at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:196) at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:378) at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:537) at
>   sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:170) at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:395) at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530) at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:234) at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:307) at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:324) at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:855)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:740)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:721)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1044)
>   at com.eoffice.xml.RSSReader.getLimitedRSS(RSSReader.java:71) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600) at
>   com.ibm.jscript.types.JavaAccessObject.call(JavaAccessObject.java:321)
>   at com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161) at
>   com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:175) at
>   com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTVariableDecl.interpret(ASTVariableDecl.java:82)
>   at
>   com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject._executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:261)
>   at
>   com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.executeFunction(FunctionObject.java:185)
>   at com.ibm.jscript.std.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:171) at
>   com.ibm.jscript.types.FBSObject.call(FBSObject.java:161) at
>   com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTCall.interpret(ASTCall.java:175) at
>   com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTVariableDecl.interpret(ASTVariableDecl.java:82)
>   at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpret(ASTProgram.java:119)
>   at com.ibm.jscript.ASTTree.ASTProgram.interpretEx(ASTProgram.java:139)
>   at
>   com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression._interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:435)
>   at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.access$1(JSExpression.java:424) at
>   com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression$2.run(JSExpression.java:414) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:284)
>   at
>   com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.interpretExpression(JSExpression.java:410)
>   at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:251)
>   at com.ibm.jscript.JSExpression.evaluateValue(JSExpression.java:234)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:220)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.javascript.JavaScriptInterpreter.interpret(JavaScriptInterpreter.java:192)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.binding.javascript.JavaScriptValueBinding.getValue(JavaScriptValueBinding.java:78)
>   at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:159) at
>   com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.convertValue(FacesUtil.java:1073) at
>   com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.html_basic.OutputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(OutputTextRenderer.java:91)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.renderkit.ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.encodeEnd(ReadOnlyAdapterRenderer.java:153)
>   at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:1005)
>   at com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:809) at
>   com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:804) at
>   com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:804) at
>   com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:804) at
>   com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.renderComponent(FacesUtil.java:804) at
>   com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx._renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1272)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.component.UIViewRootEx.renderView(UIViewRootEx.java:1210)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.doRender(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:635)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl._renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:320)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.application.ViewHandlerExImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerExImpl.java:355)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:103)
>   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:210)
>   at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:120)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.controller.FacesControllerImpl.render(FacesControllerImpl.java:264)
>   at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.serviceView(FacesServlet.java:219)
>   at
>   com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:193)
>   at com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:154) at
>   com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:137) at
>   com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:86)
>   at
>   com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:538)
>   at
>   com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1140)
>   at
>   com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:803)
>   at
>   com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:758)
>   at
>   com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:527)
>   at
>   com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1124)
>   at
>   com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:513)
>   at
>   com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:342)
>   at
>   com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:304)
>   at
>   com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:261)
>   at
>   com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:291)

When i try opening the same URL in my browser, the result is a nice RSS-XML page.. Anyone got an idea what this might be?
In the error i have removed the actual URL. The input url is on the format: http://subdomain.domain.com/somepath/somebase.nsf/form?ReadForm&newsCode=code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.net.UnknownHostException: subUrL.mydomain.com`  points there's a DNS problem. I'm assuming your have replaced the actual URL with an example. In this case check your network settings and check that JVM can resolve the URL properly.

Comment: Thank you. As you correctly points out, its most likely a DNS problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not 'most likely' but *definitely* a DNS problem. There's nothing else it can be apart from a wrong URL. It certainly *isn't* a problem with DocumentBuilder.parse(). You haven't even called it yet.